# Load entity from db inside a custom jackson deserializer the reactive way

Tags: java, jackson, vert.x, quarkus, reactive

I have a Quarkus reactive app in which I'm using a custom Jackson deserializer. In this deserializer I have to call a database.

```
public class MyTypeDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<MyType> {

    public MyTypeDeserializer() {
        this(null);
    }

    public MyTypeDeserializer(Class<?> vc) {
        super(vc);
    }

    @Override
    public MyType deserialize(
            JsonParser jsonparser, DeserializationContext context)
            throws IOException {
        // Lookup the instantiated db service which has been added to jackson on application startup
        MyTypeService service = (MyTypeService) context
                .findInjectableValue("myTypeServiceBean", null, null);
        // Get the info from json
        String info = jsonparser.getText();
        // Find myType instance in database
        return service.find("info = :info", Parameters.with("info", info)).await().indefinitely();
    }
```

Running this code leads to a:

```
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: The current thread cannot be blocked: vert.x-eventloop-thread-5
```

I understand that this error tells me that the calling thread is blocked due to `await().indefinitely()` call. But I can't find another way of retrieving the instance from the database. I have to wait until the data is loaded from the database. How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

You can't really do that in a `StdDeserializer` because there is no way to not block in the implementation of that method.

I would propose moving the load from the DB to a part of the code that is run after the deserialization takes place.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Your suggestion would be possible for sure. But I'd love to have a solution that seamlessly integrates with the deserialization. Unfortunately that doesn't seem to be possible.
I was expecting the reactive jackson deserializer returns a Uni<T> and chains the execution accordingly.
Or is there another Deserializer implementation that provides such functionality?

Comment: None that I know of